# Gobal Variable but inside the while loop and not in a function

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and Pandas.  Now I have encountered:

NameError: name 'price' is not defined

I know it is because of the while loop.  Do I need to put the while loop in a function container and use return/yield?  Any other option so that the price variable can be reached?

Enclosed please find part of my program:

```
fundspercentb = {}
for c in df.columns:
    if c[1] == 'bid':
        pass
    else:
        i = -1
        while df[c][i] == np.nan:
            i-=1
            if df[c][i] != np.nan: continue
            price=float(df[c][i])       # <----------------------------

        ma20=df[c].tail(20).astype(float).mean()
        movstd=df[c].tail(20).std()
        upperband=ma20+(2*movstd)
        lowerband=ma20-(2*movstd)
        percentb=(price-lowerband)/(upperband-lowerband)*100  # <------
        fundspercentb[c] = percentb

print fundspercent
```

Comment: Why do you have a `pass`? The only reason to use `pass` is if you want to write that code later. If, in your loop, you want to execute the `else` code-block only when `not c[1] == 'bid'`, then *do so*: `if c[1] != 'bid': the-code-you-have-in-the-else`.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, this happens if the `while` condition is never true. What they missed is that is *cannot* be true, because `NaN` behaves weird with `==` - specifically,[`np.nan == np.nan` is false](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/misc.html#ieee-754-floating-point-special-values). Use `np.isnan` instead.

The rest of the loop has issues too. The `if ...: continue` part doesn't make sense, and it should use `np.isnan` too, or perhaps thrown out entirely.

If you just want the rightmost value of `df[c]` which isn't NaN, there is probably more a more idiomatic way, possibly one using a single numpy function (which I wouldn't know, as I don't use numpy). Failing that, an explicit loop like this work too:

```
i = -1
while np.isnan(df[c][i]):
    i -= 1
price = float(df[c][i])
```

You may also want to think what happens if `df[c]` contains nothing but NaNs.
And while you're at it, ask yourself: Why does the data include NaN values at all?

Comment: Why the code raises: "TypeError: Not implemented for this type" for "while np.isnan(df[c][i]):"?  But I tested "np.isnan(df[df.columns[1]][-1])" in iPython is okay.

Comment: @TerenceNg Presumably because `df` contains some non-float things. That would explain the `float()` call at the end too. Perhaps it's better to coerce everything to float at the very beginning so you don't have to worry about this later on.

Answer (score 1):

Just give it a `None` or `0` (`0` preferably, since you are performing arithmetic on it later on) value outside the `while` loop, because if your loop never runs, `price` would never have a value, like so

```
fundspercentb = {}
for c in df.columns:
    if c[1] == 'bid':
        pass
    else:
        i = -1
        price = 0 # Desired value here
        while df[c][i] == np.nan:
            i-=1
            if df[c][i] != np.nan: continue
            price=float(df[c][i])       # <----------------------------

        ma20=df[c].tail(20).astype(float).mean()
        movstd=df[c].tail(20).std()
        upperband=ma20+(2*movstd)
        lowerband=ma20-(2*movstd)
        percentb=(price-lowerband)/(upperband-lowerband)*100  # <------
        fundspercentb[c] = percentb

print fundspercent
```

Refer to the `math.isnan` function to check for NaN's. (Given in [delnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395760/delnan)'s answer)

Also, your while loop seems kinda fishy,

```
while df[c][i] == np.nan:
      i-=1
      if df[c][i] != np.nan: continue  # This Line
      price=float(df[c][i]
```

Why `continue` it, when it would just `break` in the next iteration, just `break` it here.